# Post Hidden Input Element Values to Controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, post

I have a number of hidden input elements on my ASP.NET MVC page. They each hold an integer value. They are identified by `$('table#ratings input[name=newReviewRatings]')`.

Is it possible to post the integers in those hidden input elements using `$.post()` so that the controller is passed an array of integers?

This is probably easier using a `<form>` element and simply posting the form. But is it possible to do it using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get your array using something like this.

```
var data = [];
$('table#ratings input[name=newReviewRatings]').each(function(){
    data.push($(this).val());
});
$.post(url, data);
```

Comment: Is it `data` in place of `a`?

Comment: a is a mistake... should be data

Comment: Question? I have additional values I'm posting: `$.post(url, { id: providerId, ratings: ratings, comment: comment, name: name, title: title, location: country })`. `ratings` is my array. But the controller gets `null` when declares as either `int[] ratings` or `string[] ratings`. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't help too much on the asp side of the fence... sorry

Answer (score 2):

An ideal fit for this situation is using [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) like:

```
var data = $('#ratings input[name=newReviewRatings]').map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).get();

// Post the data to the respective url
$.post(your_url, data);
```

The `.map()` method is particularly useful for getting or setting the value of a collection of elements.